# Post a photo to a FB Page with GraphAPI in Swift

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm still struggling with Facebook Swift SDK and its GraphRequest.
I'm trying to upload a photo to a page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#upload). Apparently, all fields described at the bottom pf the page can be used as multipart from data fields. I guess the image should be sent using the "source" entry.
I think I found a way to use multipart form data :

```
        let image =  GraphRequestDataAttachment(data: data, filename: "source", contentType: "image/heic")
        let text = GraphRequestDataAttachment(data: contentData, filename: "caption", contentType: "text")
        GraphRequest
            .init(graphPath: "\(pageId)/photos",
                parameters: ["source" : image, "caption" : text],
                httpMethod: .post)
            .start { (connexion, result, error) in
            completion(Result.success(true))
        }
```

Before that I already requested the new permissions pages_manage_posts and not the deprecated publish_actions.

However, I get a 403 error when trying to achieve this

```
 error =         {
        code = 200;
        "fbtrace_id" = AyiF3Bo05RA5Vqe3I9P24Fy;
        message = "(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
```

I also tried to use the pageId/feed instead of the pageId/photos, request other permissions ("pages_manage_posts", "pages_manage_metadata", "pages_read_engagement"), nothing works.

Has anyone encountered the same issue or has some clues about this damn GraphAPI ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you tried to use a user token for the request, and not actually a page token.

Comment: Ok thanks @CBroe. I should include a pageToken (got from the permission result) in the multipart forma data then ?

Comment: Yes, add that to the rest of the parameters, under the parameter name `access_token`.

Comment: Still the same @CBroe : rror =         {
            code = 200;
            "fbtrace_id" = "A57qV5j9-rwxXO9EEC_bZfC";
            message = "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\\n          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \\\n          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\\n          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \\\n          sufficient administrative permission";
            type = OAuthException;
        };

Comment: according to this error message the page id from your example code is a group id. That's something different and you need the prerequisites mentioned in the error message.  App installed in the group and the suitable permissions ...

Comment: Thanks @Norbert. I retrieve the id from the me/accounts request using this code : guard let result = result as? [String:Any],
                                  let dataArray = result["data"] as? Array<Any>,
                                  let data = dataArray.first as? [String:Any],
                                  let pageId = data["id"] as? String,
                                  let access = data["access_token"] as? String else { return }. It seems that I retrieve the id associated with the page, not a group Id right ? Thanks.

Comment: What is really strange is that when I use the graphAPI explorer with the same parameters, it works :-/